# Reshape weekly data

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2

I have one data set with weekly sales for different beverages.Data set contain values from 1 week of 2019 until 18 week into 2020. You can see below code for data

```
        ARTEFICIAL_DATA<-data.frame(structure(list(year_week = c("2019 01", "2019 02", "2019 03", 
                                                                 "2019 04", "2019 05", "2019 06", "2019 07", "2019 08", "2019 09", 
                                                                 "2019 10", "2019 11", "2019 12", "2019 13", "2019 14", "2019 15", 
                                                                 "2019 16", "2019 17", "2019 18", "2019 19", "2019 20", "2019 21", 
                                                                 "2019 22", "2019 23", "2019 24", "2019 25", "2019 26", "2019 27", 
                                                                 "2019 28", "2019 29", "2019 30", "2019 31", "2019 32", "2019 33", 
                                                                 "2019 34", "2019 35", "2019 36", "2019 37", "2019 38", "2019 39", 
                                                                 "2019 40", "2019 41", "2019 42", "2019 43", "2019 44", "2019 45", 
                                                                 "2019 46", "2019 47", "2019 48", "2019 49", "2019 50", "2019 51", 
                                                                 "2019 52", "2020 01", "2020 02", "2020 03", "2020 04", "2020 05", 
                                                                 "2020 06", "2020 07", "2020 08", "2020 09", "2020 10", "2020 11", 
                                                                 "2020 12", "2020 13", "2020 14", "2020 15", "2020 16", "2020 17", 
                                                                 "2020 18"), Year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                                                      2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                                                      2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                                                      2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                                                      2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                                                      2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                                                                      2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), Pepsi = c(309, 
                                                                                                                                                 201, 369, 211, 262, 306, 477, 269, 175, 315, 373, 309, 280, 450, 
                                                                                                                                                 331, 394, 295, 266, 349, 434, 247, 302, 423, 347, 384, 327, 369, 
                                                                                                                                                 373, 380, 305, 432, 371, 437, 242, 270, 444, 432, 331, 309, 422, 
                                                                                                                                                 300, 495, 285, 408, 336, 484, 324, 327, 359, 441, 392, 373, 168, 
                                                                                                                                                 137, 404, 325, 279, 320, 461, 311, 336, 286, 333, 299, 209, 199, 
                                                                                                                                                 197, 344, 170, 176), Coke = c(139, 119, 189, 160, 184, 174, 246, 
                                                                                                                                                                               203, 117, 193, 233, 226, 219, 228, 219, 238, 220, 136, 198, 229, 
                                                                                                                                                                               172, 225, 191, 183, 224, 223, 205, 232, 228, 215, 193, 219, 205, 
                                                                                                                                                                               178, 172, 219, 206, 245, 234, 218, 180, 269, 220, 224, 211, 253, 
                                                                                                                                                                               231, 239, 225, 247, 270, 265, 68, 87, 211, 193, 200, 188, 247, 
                                                                                                                                                                               216, 226, 203, 231, 183, 143, 147, 143, 162, 125, 122), Fanta = c(24, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 18, 22, 20, 22, 20, 25, 23, 13, 22, 25, 24, 23, 31, 22, 23, 20, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 23, 19, 20, 19, 22, 22, 21, 26, 21, 27, 24, 22, 23, 21, 25, 19, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 21, 20, 22, 23, 23, 21, 32, 21, 28, 22, 23, 24, 24, 23, 26, 24, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 23, 28, 29, 7, 18, 23, 27, 25, 24, 27, 24, 29, 24, 24, 20, 17, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 21, 19, 13, 12, 16), Beer = c(145, 64, 158, 31, 56, 112, 206, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               42, 45, 100, 114, 59, 38, 191, 89, 133, 56, 107, 131, 184, 56, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               55, 211, 142, 134, 84, 137, 116, 130, 66, 218, 127, 213, 43, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               78, 202, 203, 62, 54, 171, 99, 198, 44, 161, 100, 206, 70, 61, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               110, 172, 94, 79, 93, 32, 171, 105, 54, 109, 187, 71, 81, 58, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               78, 96, 49, 31, 34, 168, 33, 39), Juice = c(28, 40, 105, 26, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           41, 31, 96, 37, 20, 46, 78, 53, 29, 57, 46, 111, 49, 18, 58, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           112, 37, 43, 38, 93, 48, 69, 43, 57, 114, 43, 48, 47, 141, 35, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           47, 69, 158, 43, 49, 29, 34, 139, 40, 42, 38, 132, 38, 42, 41, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           103, 42, 48, 30, 22, 136, 39, 37, 39, 92, 40, 40, 37, 67, 73, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           31, 23, 27, 102, 31, 25), Lemonade = c(111, 22, 31, 0, 12, 77, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  95, 0, 22, 50, 22, 2, 3, 129, 39, 0, 2, 84, 70, 42, 16, 6, 168, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  31, 76, 10, 88, 37, 3, 17, 166, 73, 37, 5, 27, 128, 20, 5, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  136, 61, 32, 0, 113, 53, 52, 28, 14, 62, 54, 39, 22, 63, 8, 14, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  63, 16, 69, 85, 26, 40, 19, 2, 17, 16, 8, 5, 50, 1, 13), Radler = c(2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1, 21, 2, 1, 2, 11, 2, 1, 2, 12, 2, 3, 3, 2, 19, 2, 4, 2, 28, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2, 3, 3, 16, 8, 3, 3, 19, 11, 3, 2, 4, 34, 1, 3, 3, 22, 11, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      4, 1, 24, 1, 3, 7, 20, 1, 3, 3, 12, 8, 2, 1, 2, 21, 3, 2, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      10, 5, 1, 2, 10, 5, 2, 1, 2, 15, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -70L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

So next should how to convert this data like pic below

[image]

I try with melt function from reshape2 package but I got table which is not good.

```
ARTEFICIAL_DATA1<-melt(ARTEFICIAL_DATA,id.variables = 'year_week')
```

So can anybody help how to reshape data (melt,pivot whatever) like table of the pic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ARTEFICIAL_DATA %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = c(year_week, Pepsi:Radler)) %>% 
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 52 x 16
#   year_week_2019 year_week_2020 Pepsi_2019 Pepsi_2020 Coke_2019 Coke_2020 Fanta_2019 Fanta_2020 Beer_2019 Beer_2020
#   <chr>          <chr>               <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 2019 01        2020 01               309        168       139        68         24          7       145        93
# 2 2019 02        2020 02               201        137       119        87         18         18        64        32
# 3 2019 03        2020 03               369        404       189       211         22         23       158       171
# 4 2019 04        2020 04               211        325       160       193         20         27        31       105
# 5 2019 05        2020 05               262        279       184       200         22         25        56        54
# 6 2019 06        2020 06               306        320       174       188         20         24       112       109
# 7 2019 07        2020 07               477        461       246       247         25         27       206       187
# 8 2019 08        2020 08               269        311       203       216         23         24        42        71
# 9 2019 09        2020 09               175        336       117       226         13         29        45        81
#10 2019 10        2020 10               315        286       193       203         22         24       100        58
# … with 42 more rows, and 6 more variables: Juice_2019 <dbl>, Juice_2020 <dbl>, Lemonade_2019 <dbl>,
#   Lemonade_2020 <dbl>, Radler_2019 <dbl>, Radler_2020 <dbl>
```

Comment: I check code but is not same like example.Namely maximum number of rows should be 52 (number of weeks in year) but this line of code 70 rows.So please check again if you can.Thank you in advance.

Comment: @silent_hunter it is not recommended to have duplicate column names, so it is appended with year as suffiix to diifferentiate column